# How to get the value and text color of a ListViewItem in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, listviewitem

I would like to get the value of one row in my `ListViewItem` control and then based on that value decide if the color should be red or green.

I tried the following:

```
foreach (var item in listView1.Items)
{
    var listViewItem = listView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
    if (item.IsOnline == "online")
    {
        listViewItem.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
    }
    else
    {             
        listViewItem.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

But this way I can't get the value from `item.IsOnline`. If I use the `foreach` like this `foreach (var item in listView1.Items)` then I can get the values but can't change the foreground color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define an `ItemContainerStyle` in your XAML markup:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="online">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. I had the `Style` element already inside the `ListView` element but was missing the `ItemContainerStyle` and of course it didn't work because of that. I have two columns in the `ListView`. Is there any way to change the color of only one column?

Comment: @JedatKinports: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.